# Rails: How does persist? work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two instance variables: **@var_from_new** and **@var_from_find_by**.

**@var_from_new** was created by

```
@var_from_new = EmailAddress.new
```

**@var_from_find_by** was created by

```
@var_from_find_by.find_by_email_address(email_address_params[:email_address])
```

When I examine both variables with a debugger, both instance variables contain exactly the same contents.  Yet

```
@var_from_new.persisted?    # false
@var_from_find_by.persisted # true
```

How does Rails know?

Comment: "contain exactly the same contents." - I don't think so.

Comment: When I examined @ var_from_new and @ var_from_find_by using the byebug debugger, I did not see any differences.  What I failed to do was examine @ var_from_new.instance_variables to see if there were any differences and, obviously, there was.

Comment: No differences at all? Not even id?

Comment: No differences at all. Not even id.

Comment: I find it hard to believe. If you don't mind, what _exactly_ did you do and what _exactly_ did you see? Post to gist for formatting.

Comment: No differences at all.  Not even id.  

More information at  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49464389/rails-attempting-save-an-existiing-row-but-rails-generates-sql-insert-instead-o

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How does Rails know?

One record was loaded from database, the other was initialized in-memory and not yet persisted. The fact that they may have the same values for most of the fields is irrelevant. If you were asking, what is it that rails is doing, here's how you can find out:

```
[1] pry(main)> show-source EmailAddress#persisted?

From: /Users/sergio/.gem/ruby/2.4.2/gems/activerecord-5.1.5/lib/active_record/persistence.rb @ line 98:
Owner: ActiveRecord::Persistence
Visibility: public
Number of lines: 4

def persisted?
  sync_with_transaction_state
  !(@new_record || @destroyed)
end
```

As it is now apparent, `persisted?` uses an instance variable `@new_record` which you probably didn't see/notice in the debugger.

(*this code uses gem `pry` via [pry-rails](https://github.com/rweng/pry-rails)*)

Comment: No, I didn't notice it because I wasn't looking for @var_from_new.instance_variables and @ var_from_find_by.instance_variables.

I thank you for your answer.  It cleared a lot of things up for me.

Comment: Oh, and for those unfamiliar with it, if you want to see the value of, say, the instance variable, @ new_record, associated with, say, @ var_from_find_by without having to add an accessor method, you can do @ var_from_find_by.instance_variable_get(:@new_record)